# Cartan-Hadamard's Theorem, Completeness

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Theorem: Let $(M^n,g)$ complete, simply connected Riemannian manifold with non-positive sectional curvature. Then $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Question: Can we change complete to "every two points can be joined by a minimizing geodesic"?

Comment: I do not have an answer, just few remarks. Answer is positive if $M$ is homogeneous (by using the developing map to the model homogeneous space). It is probably also positive for surfaces (using Gauss-Bonet formula, but I did not check the details). In general, I expect negative answer, but it is hard to construct an example. One can first try to construct a locally $CAT(0)$ example which is simply-connected and where every two points are connected by a minimizing geodesic,but even this is hard. 

Comment: In the case $n=2$ I meant the question about injectivity of the exponential map, since the topological statement is clear. 

Comment: Cartan-Hadamard does hold for some classes of incomplete nonpositively curved manifold, see Bowditch'es paper,  http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102366182, Pacific J. Math. (1996)

Comment: @Igor: nice reference!

Answer (score 3):

Take a point $x \in M$ and consider the star-shaped open set  $U \subset T_xM$ where the exponential
$$
exp_x : U \rightarrow M
$$
is defined. $U$ is diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n$ and the map ${\rm exp_x}$ is

(1) a local diffeomorphism (because of the absence of conjugate points = singularities of ${\rm exp}_x$);

(2) surjective (because I can join any other point of $M$ to $x$ by a geodesic).

I guess there is no problem and $M$ is diffeomorphic to $U$. Right??

**Edit.** As Claudio points out, the fact that ${\rm exp}_x$ is surjective and a local diffeomorphism does not imply that it is a covering map. Hence we cannot use the homotopy lifting property to conclude that it is injective and a diffeomorphism.

Comment: It is not clear to me that $\exp_x$ is injective (equivalently, a covering).
 

Comment: @Claudio: You're probably right. A surjective local homeomorphism is not necesarily a covering. I just can't see right now where this comes up in the standard proof of the Cartan-Hadamard theorem, but I've been grading all day ...

Comment: @Claudio: You're right. That is the issue. 

Comment: If you look at Karcher's proof in his paper on Riemannian Comparison Constructions he observes that the exponential map is locally expanding when the curvature is non-positive and this should imply that the exponential map is a covering .

Comment: Mohan: This type of argument need completeness. There are local isometries which are not covering maps. 

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be completion of $(M,g)$.
Note that $X$ is simply connected.
It follows since any loop in $X$ is a limit of a broken geodesic in $(M,g)$.

Therefore $X$ is CAT(0), in particular any two points are joined by unique geodesic.
Therefore $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ as any star-shaped domain (thanks to alvarezpaiva).

Comment: @Jason: to get $S^1$ as completion you have to take the subspace metric on $M$, but the metric is not geodesic: if $x,y$ are points near $p$ in $S^1$ such that $p$ is between $x$ and $y$, then any geodesic in $M$ that joints $x$, $y$ has length about $2\pi$. The correct metric on $M$ is the one induced by Riemannian metric on $S^1$ whose completion is $[0,2\pi]$. 

Comment: @epsilon-delta: The space $X$ (a priori) need not be locally $CAT(0)$. One cn easily construct (non-simply-connected) incomplete flat surfaces whose completion is not even locally contractible.  

Comment: @Misha, I am sure this is true, but do not see a simple proof. I will delete my answer once the true answer is found.

Comment: @epsilon-delta: Take $X$ be the complement of the closed round ball in ${\mathbb R}^3$. Then $X$ is (locally) flat. Its metric completion is not a $CAT(0)$ space. Of course, $X$ is not convex...